# Aurelia: Stylesheet loaded but not removed

Tags: css, aurelia

In an aurelia project I have several components that import additional stylesheets, e.g. from semantic-ui. After leaving the components page, the stylesheet is still active and not removed. Is it possible to 'unload' the stylesheets?

Comment: Aurelia injects css into the head section of html, it smartly avoid double injection. But it did not provide any way to unload injected css, as far as I know.

Comment: But if you use `DOM.injectStyles(...)` directly, it support an id to the style tag, which then you can repeatedly replace the same style tag. https://github.com/aurelia/pal/blob/fc3d10a48e1b1e82f4efc9ddcc98c998b4cdf3cf/src/index.js#L349

Answer (score 1):

### Update (2018-03-27):

I submitted a PR to enable this as an opt-in, you can keep track of it here: https://github.com/aurelia/templating-resources/pull/344

### Original answer:

A word of warning, this is untested and aurelia-internals-hacky.

What you *could* do is override the default `CSSViewEngineHooks` and `CSSResource` classes to keep track of the style elements it injects, and then add an `beforeUnbind` hook to remove the styles again.. before unbind (right after detached)

Unfortunately the `CSSResource` class is not exported from `aurelia-templating-resources` so we need to go one layer deeper and overwrite the existing style loader plugins that returns instances of `CSSResource`.

**Here's how:**

First we grab the code from `aurelia-templating-resources/src/css-resource.js`, put it in our own `src/css-resource.js/ts` and make a few tweaks to it (don't think too much of the size, it's just a copy-paste with a few small tweaks, annotated with comments):

```
import {ViewResources, resource, ViewCompileInstruction} from 'aurelia-templating';
import {Loader} from 'aurelia-loader';
import {Container} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {relativeToFile} from 'aurelia-path';
import {DOM, FEATURE} from 'aurelia-pal';

let cssUrlMatcher = /url\((?!['"]data)([^)]+)\)/gi;

function fixupCSSUrls(address, css) {
  if (typeof css !== 'string') {
    throw new Error(`Failed loading required CSS file: ${address}`);
  }
  return css.replace(cssUrlMatcher, (match, p1) => {
    let quote = p1.charAt(0);
    if (quote === '\'' || quote === '"') {
      p1 = p1.substr(1, p1.length - 2);
    }
    return 'url(\'' + relativeToFile(p1, address) + '\')';
  });
}

class CSSResource {
  constructor(address: string) {
    this.address = address;
    this._scoped = null;
    this._global = false;
    this._alreadyGloballyInjected = false;
  }

  initialize(container: Container, target: Function): void {
    this._scoped = new target(this);
  }

  register(registry: ViewResources, name?: string): void {
    if (name === 'scoped') {
      registry.registerViewEngineHooks(this._scoped);
    } else {
      this._global = true;
    }
  }

  load(container: Container): Promise<CSSResource> {
    return container.get(Loader)
      .loadText(this.address)
      .catch(err => null)
      .then(text => {
        text = fixupCSSUrls(this.address, text);
        this._scoped.css = text;
        if (this._global) {
          this._alreadyGloballyInjected = true;
          // DOM.injectStyles(text); <- replace this
          // this is one of the two possible moments where the style is injected
          // _scoped is the CSSViewEngineHooks instance, and we handle the removal there
          this._scoped.styleNode = DOM.injectStyles(text);
        }
      });
  }
}

class CSSViewEngineHooks {
  constructor(owner: CSSResource) {
    this.owner = owner;
    this.css = null;
  }

  beforeCompile(content: DocumentFragment, resources: ViewResources, instruction: ViewCompileInstruction): void {
    if (instruction.targetShadowDOM) {
      DOM.injectStyles(this.css, content, true);
    } else if (FEATURE.scopedCSS) {
      let styleNode = DOM.injectStyles(this.css, content, true);
      styleNode.setAttribute('scoped', 'scoped');
    } else if (this._global && !this.owner._alreadyGloballyInjected) {
      // DOM.injectStyles(this.css); <- replace this
      // save a reference to the node so we can easily remove it later
      this.styleNode = DOM.injectStyles(this.css);
      this.owner._alreadyGloballyInjected = true;
    }
  }

  // this is the hook we add, here we remove the node again
  beforeUnbind(): void {
    if (this._global && this.owner._alreadyGloballyInjected) {
      DOM.removeNode(this.styleNode);
      this.owner._alreadyGloballyInjected = false;
    }
  }
}

export function _createCSSResource(address: string): Function {
  @resource(new CSSResource(address))
  class ViewCSS extends CSSViewEngineHooks {}
  return ViewCSS;
}
```

Then, in our `main.ts/js` we do the same thing `aurelia-templating-resources.js` does, but with our own version.
So we do this **after** the call to `aurelia.use.standardConfiguration()` etc, to override the existing one

```
let viewEngine = config.container.get(ViewEngine);
let styleResourcePlugin = {
  fetch(address) {
    return { [address]: _createCSSResource(address) };
  }
};
['.css', '.less', '.sass', '.scss', '.styl'].forEach(ext => viewEngine.addResourcePlugin(ext, styleResourcePlugin));
```

And that should pretty much do the trick.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a plugin to resolve the issue:
https://github.com/jbockle/aurelia-useable-style-loader

But for the latest Webpack `webpack.config.js` should be a little bit different than in a plugin readme.

You should load `.css` files this way:

```
   use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader', options: { injectType: 'lazyStyleTag' } },
          'css-loader'
        ]
```

Instead of this:

```
  use: ['style-loader/useable', 'css-loader']
```